# Error disabling scheduled query: Error updating disabled property. Please try again later

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to disable a scheduled query in BigQuery web interface, I get this error:

Error updating disabled property. Please try again later.

I think that previously I made this kind of updates without problems... The "solution" I found is to remove the scheduled query, but in fact, I don't want to lose the query. Is this a new bug of this functionality or am I missing something?

Comment: I can confirm that I am also seeing this bug recently.

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior too. I found an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/147972076) where it was reported to the BigQuery Engineering team. You can subscribe to it (clicking on the star next to the title) to receive notifications regarding its progress.